# Issue having connection with external display MacBook Pro Mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2012 with macOS 10.15 (Catalina),
I want to connect an external display which is an HP E230t, I am trying to connect the external display. My MacBook works fine but my monitor is not detecting any input from my computer,

I have done this scenario 2 times,

1. I used an external display connector and it doesn't show any action on my Mac or External Display screen
2. I replaced the previous connector with a new one and this time it shows me the **Arrangement** section in the **Display Preferences** of the Mac but the External display won't work

**What is the problem? Is it my Mac or I don't know how to operate External Display?**

Note: My external display is fully functional if I used it with another System/PC.

[image: Screenshot of the Display Preferences showing only one monitor while two are connected]
This is the image I shared when I connect the screen with Mac.

Comment: I can't help directly, but, just to be sure, have you checked the cable to the monitor? (I am assuming it is not the same one that you used with the PC.)

Comment: Is the external display connector using USB-C on the Mac?

Comment: On a 2012 MBP? However, still the question how you are connecting the display (mini-DP or HDMI) and are you sure the cable works (i.e. it works with a different setup). Also can you try the MacBook with a different monitor? You need to narrow down the issue to the monitor, cable or the MacBook.

Comment: @X_841 I am using (Thunderbolt to HDMI) cable connector, According to me, it is working because I used two connectors first one doesn't show me anything and the second one shows me the arrangement section on display, and now I am using the second one, which makes me believe that connector is working somehow. What do you suggest?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly: you tried these different ports on the MBP or on the monitor, or both? Just because "something" happens, it doesn't mean the port is fully operational. As I said you should do the following: test every indivudual component (i.e. cable, monitor and MacBook) independently. E.g. take a different computer and monitor and check the cable, take a different laptop (maybe at work or at a friends) and try there. You have to make sure that you take a working system and only *one by one* try your hardware.